# Al hacer click, redireccione y filtre productos por categoria selecionada

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Lo que necesito es realizar una funcion que me redireccione al seleccionar un link y me muestre los productos de la categoria seleccionada.

**Como armar la funcion correctamente para que filtre por categoria seleccionada,muestre los productos de esa categoria?**

Lo que tengo:

*El link donde se hace click para seleccionar esa categoria en particular*

```
<a href="/stock/products/?categoryId=<?php echo $categoryId; ?>" class="ViewProducts"><?php echo __("Ver productos"); ?></a>
```

*El filtro general por categorias*

```
filterData.category = $('#categoriesFilter').find('option:selected').val();
```

Ejemplo:

colocandole directamente el numero de la categoria, redirecciona y muestra solo los productos de esa categoria.

```
filterData.category = 3;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la imagen de la pagina de productos a donde soy redirigido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añados partes de mi CategoryController.php:

```
* @param $categories
 * @return bool|string
 */
public function renderCategoryTree($categories = [])
{
    if (empty($categories)) {
        $categories = StockService::getInstance()->getCompanyCategories();
    }

    if (empty($categories)) {
        return false;
    }

    $content = "";

    foreach ($categories as $rootCategory) {
        $content .= $this->parseOneCategory($rootCategory);
    }

    $tree = new HtmlView('_category_categoryTree');

    $tree->addObject('categoryTree', $content);

    return $tree->returnContent();
}

/**
 * @param  array $category
 * @return string
 */
private function parseOneCategory($category)
{
    $categoryName = $category['name'];
    $categoryId = $category['id'];
    $childCategories = "";

    if (!empty($category['childs'])) {
        $hasChilds = true;
        foreach ($category['childs'] as $child) {
            $childCategories .= $this->parseOneCategory($child);
        }
    } else {
        $hasChilds = false;
    }

    $oneCategory = new HtmlView('_category_categoryTree_category');
    $oneCategory->setDataArray(array(
        'categoryId' => $categoryId,
        'categoryName' => $categoryName,
        'hasChilds' => $hasChilds,
        'childCategories' => $childCategories,
        'visible' => $category['visibility'],
        'totalProducts' => $category['total_products'],
        'categoryProducts' => $category['category_product_count'],
        'sort' => $category['sort']
    ));

    return $oneCategory->returnContent();
}
```

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
var getParameterByName = function (name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';

    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

y

```
var categoryId  = getParameterByName('categoryId', window.location.href )    
    filterData.category = categoryId
```

Comment: Buenas! Tienes que redireccionar si o si? o puedes mostrar los productos en la misma página? En el caso de redireccionar, tendrías que guardar el filtro en sessionsStorage y recuperarla uan vez se recargue la pagina.

Comment: En principio estoy en la pagina Stock/Categorias y al hacer click te lleva a stock/productos . o sea todo esta dentro de Stock.

Comment: Vale, osea primero seleccionas la categoría y posteriormente te redirecciona? Correcto?

Comment: Exacto. Hago click en "Ver productos" que es el boton que comenté arriba (todas las categorias tienen ese boton como opcion) y posteriormente me redirecciona a stock/products/?categoryId=3 (de haber seleccionado esa categoria n°3) pero muestra todos los productos, no solo los de esa categoria.

Comment: entiendo, faltaría ver el archivo products.php para tener una imagen completa :)

Comment: Ahi edite pero no se que mas te puedo pasar para que puedas tener la información completa :)

Comment: Me refería al código donde coges la url y filtras por el código de producto para mostrarlo. si me dices que te los muestra todos esto significa que alguna parte del código falla. Otra cosa, veo que en tu url tienes `products/?categoryId=9`. No sera por la barra esta que va despues de los `products` por lo que te falla?

Comment: Puede ser, si te fijas en *<a href="/stock/products/?categoryId=<?php echo $categoryId; ?>" class="ViewProducts"><?php echo __("Ver productos"); ?></a>* es donde coloque directamente. pero no se si esta bien o deberia ser en la funcion

Comment: puede colocar un minimo de tu codigo especificamene el html de como estas tu estructura? no se si lo sepas pero esto es [stack overflow es](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) no instagram asi que requerimos codigo no imagenes!

Comment: tienes un archivo que se llama products.php verdad? Si es asi, muestralo para tener una idea mas clara. Solo el codigo. Gracias.
p.d.: @Bryro no hace falta decirlo de esta manera, se puede invitar a que lea [ask]!

Comment: He agregado codigo de mi CategoryController. Mientras busco el products.php que tambien tengo. @IvanIsayenko

Comment: Perfecto! Si ya lo has solucionado, por favor escribe tu respuesta y votala para que se vea que ya esta solucionado :)

Comment: gracias por tus comentarios @IvanIsayenko te comparto lo que ahora con esta solucion me resta hacer. https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/245512/118416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
var getParameterByName = function (name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';

    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

y

```
var categoryId  = getParameterByName('categoryId', window.location.href )    
    filterData.category = categoryId
```