# ¿Como mostrar categoria seleccionada en dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, ajax

**Lo que necesito es que muestre la categoría seleccionada previamente en stock/categories y la muestre en el dropdown del FILTRO DE CATEGORIAS en stock/productos.**

*Lo que tengo:*

Selecciono "Ver productos" en una categoria especifica en stock/categories con el siguiente enlace

```
<a href="/stock/products/?categoryId=<?php echo $categoryId; ?>" class="ViewProducts"><?php echo __("Ver productos"); ?></a>
```

Me redirije a stock/products y me muestra solo los productos de esa categoria seleccionada y en la url me figuran el filtro por categoria '?categoryId='

***Mi codigo actual:***

En este filtro por categorias es el que maneja el dropdown al momento de ver el arbol de categorias disponible (sino me equivoco)

```
  /**
 * Filtro por categorías
 */

var loadCategoriesFilter = function() {
    var url = '/stock/ajaxGetCategoriesTree/';

    $.post(url, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
        categories = [];

    $.each(response.categoryTree, function(index, element){
         categories.push(element);
        });

        getParentCategories(categories);
        }
    }, 'json');
};
```

El codigo que muestra las categorias en el dropdown

```
$('#categoriesFilter').live('change', function(e) {
        var appliedFiltersBox = $('.appliedFilters');
        var categoryFilterAppliedText = $('#categoriesFilter option:selected').text();
        var visibilityFilterText = setVisibilityFilterText($('.tab.active').attr('id'));
        applyFilter();
        $('.productVisibility').text(visibilityFilterText)
        $('.categoryFilterText').show();
        $('.categoryFilterApplied').text(categoryFilterAppliedText);
        if(appliedFiltersBox.is(":hidden")){
            showAppliedFilters();
        }
    });
```

Cuando carga la pagina se inician los filtros principales.

```
if (!emptyProducts) {
        loadCategoriesFilter();
        loadStockFilter();

        var categoryId = getParameterByName('categoryId', window.location.href);

        if(categoryId !== null) {
            applyFilter({page: 1}, {category: categoryId});
         } else {
            applyFilter();
         }
    }
```

y por si suma, para entender mejor, aca el codigo de getParamByName para el categoryId en la URL.

```
var getParameterByName = function (name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';

        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Pueden ver el proceso previo de llegar hasta aca en [Al hacer click, redireccione y filtre productos por categoria selecionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/245304/118416)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné con:

```
var loadCategoriesFilter = function() {
    var url = '/stock/ajaxGetCategoriesTree/';

    $.post(url, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            categories = [];
            $.each(response.categoryTree, function(index, element){
            categories.push(element);
            });

            getParentCategories(categories);

            //fix load category filter by params
            $('#categoriesFilter').val(getParameterByName('categoryId', window.location.href));
            $('#categoriesFilter').trigger("liszt:updated");
        }
    }, 'json');
};
```